# Cast an int to a Float in Swift

Tags: swift

Im trying to cast the results of a calculation (ShotPercentage) to a Float and present the results in the App as a 89 percent for example. But I am struggling with the type casting any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    // calculate shot percentage
    shotPercentage = makeCounter / totalCounter
    shotPercentageLabel.text = "\(shotPercentage)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a conversion to your `Float`result like this.

`shotPercentage = Int(makeCounter / totalCounter)`

Comment: Ok, so I search the net, and played around with the code a bit  and came up with the following:                                                                                              shotPercentageD = Double (makeCounter &/ totalCounter)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var shotPercentageInt: Int
    shotPercentageInt = 3/5
    println("\(shotPercentageInt*100)%") // 0% because 3/5 = 0.6 -> Int = 0

    //
    var shotPercentageFloat: Float
    shotPercentageFloat = 3/5
    println("\(shotPercentageFloat*100)%") // 60.0% because 3/5 = 0.6 -> Float = 60%

    // Convert Float to Int
    var shotPercentageFloatToInt: Int
    shotPercentageFloatToInt = Int(shotPercentageFloat)
    println("\(shotPercentageFloat)") // 0.6
// It's amazing
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use NSNumberFormatter.  It does well going to strings and coming from strings.  Regardless, it would look like:

```
let makeCounter = 15
let totalCounter = 20
let shotPercentage:Float = makeCounter / totalCounter
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .PercentStyle
if let percentString = formatter.stringFromNumber(shotPercentage) {
    shotPercentageLabel.text = percentString
}
```

In this case the label would read 75%, as the formatter will include the percent sign for you.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the suggestion!